# Cache-control max-age meta tag not registering

Tags: http-headers, meta-tags, cache-control, html-head

I've put this in my head section. It appears in the page source in the browser.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=1209600">
```

However, when I look in the Chrome extension `Live HTTP Headers`, it says the following.

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 5849
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 05 Apr 2014 04:29:16 GMT
Expires: Sat, 05 Apr 2014 04:29:16 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 05 Apr 2014 03:33:19 GMT
```

The `max-age` isn't registering. I've emptied the browser cache but it makes no difference.

Any explanations? [This](https://bookacasual.com.au) is the site, incidentally.

UPDATES:

Firebug similarly records `Cache-Control: max-age=0`.

Google also makes clear [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/caching) that `max-age` overrides the `Expires` header (which I don't set) and that you don't need both.

Comment: A meta tag will not affect the HTTP headers returned by the server. But the browser should read both the headers and the meta tags to apply its caching rules. You just won't be able to debug how the browser interprets it by looking at the headers, you will need to examine it's behaviour, ie. does it make a new web request next time it needs that resource, or does it fetch it from cache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use tools like Live HTTP Headers, they show you the *actual* HTTP headers sent by the browser. What they do with `meta` tags used to simulate HTTP headers is a different issue. We can expect any conflict to be resolved in favor of the actual headers. (This has been normatively specified in HTML specs for `Content-Type` headers.)

To control cacheing, you should (at least primarily) use server configuration. See [Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Are you suggesting, then, that the server configuration is overriding the meta tag?